# IIS - redirect urls which are not ending with aspx to some page

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am using intelligencia urlrewriter and I want to redirect all urls which are **not ending with .aspx or .html** to some page of web application but not able to figure out regex pattern required for it. I have tried pattern

```
^(?!.*[.]aspx$).*$
```

but seems like it is now working with IIS rewite rule or i am missing something. I need help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use Intelligencia `UrlRewriter`? Or IIS rewrite rules would also be OK? Seems like you are trying both...

If you can use IIS rewrite rules, then you can negate the whole regex pattern, for example:

```
<rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^.*\.(html|aspx)$" negate="true" />
     <action type="Redirect" url="/" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

**Edit**

Regex to match all URLs not ending with .aspx or .html

```
^.*(?<!\.(html|aspx))$
```

I haven't tested it on Intelligencia `UrlRewriter` though.

Comment: I want to use Intelligencia UrlRewriter and i want to pass value after / to another page as query string parameter

Comment: I've added an edit with regex including negation, however haven't tested on Intelligencia `UrlRewriter`. Does this help?